# parsing string to datetime: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to parse json. I'm getting string value which is actually datetime:

> 11/1/2017 12:00:40 AM

and when I'm trying to parse it

```
DateTime.ParseExact("11/1/2017 12:00:40 AM", "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

What's wrong?

Comment: shouldnt it be `11/01`?

Comment: The format specifier characters are case sensitive.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon yeah it should but I can't change it. this format is from api

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your format string doesn't match your data, and isn't right for .NET anyway. Different languages/platforms use different format strings - always check the docs for the one you're using. Here's your format string:

```
"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM"
```

You need to read the documentation for [custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). In your case:

- `MM` means two-digit months; it's not clear whether you'll actually have those, given that you don't have two-digit days
- `DD` doesn't have any meaning; you meant `dd`, but that shouldn't match either as your day appears to be single-digits
- `YYYY` doesn't have any meaning; you meant `yyyy`
- `HH` is 24-hour; you meant `hh`
- `MI` is a single-digit month followed by `I`; you meant `mm` for minutes
- `SS` doesn't have any meaning; you meant `ss`
- `AM` should be `tt` to match the AM/PM format specifier

So I think you want your format string to be

```
"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
```

Answer (score 2):

repalce

`"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM"`

with

`"MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`

- `MM` for 2 digit month or `M` for one digit - **not sure about your input**
- `d` 1 digit day
- `yyyy` 4 digit year
- `hh` 12 hour format
- `mm` minutes
- `ss` seconds
- `tt` AM/PM

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)